# Managing Dependencies - pipeline code spans multiple files

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, python-packaging

I'm facing problems running a streaming pipeline on `DataFlowRunner` after separating out the  “main pipeline code” and “custom transforms code”to multiple files, as described here: [Multiple File Dependencies](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies) - no element (pubs message) is read into the pipeline. Neither the tabs - JOB LOGS, WORKER LOGS, JOB ERROR REPORTING in (new) Dataflow UI - report any errors. Job ID: `2020-04-06_15_23_52-4004061030939218807` if someone wants to have a look...

Pipeline minimal code (**BEFORE**):
**pipeline.py**

```py
row = p | "read_sub" >> pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUB,with_attributes=True,) \
        | "add_timestamps" >> beam.Map(add_timestamps)
```

`add_timestamps` is my custom transform

```py
def add_timestamps(e):
    payload = e.data.decode()
    return {"message":payload}
```

All works fine when `add_timestamps` and the pipeline code are in same file **pipeline.py**.

**AFTER** I restructured the files as follows:

```
root_dir/
   pipeline.py
   setup.py
   my_transforms/
      __init__py.py
      transforms.py
```

where, **setup.py**

```py
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
   name='my-custom-transforms-package',
   version='1.0',
   install_requires=["datetime"],
   packages= ['my_transforms'] #setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

all the `add_timestamps` transform code moved to **transforms.py** (under **my_transforms** package directory)

In my **pipeline.py** I now import and use the transform as follows:

```py
from my_transforms.transforms import add_timestamps
row = p | "read_sub" >> pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUB,with_attributes=True,) \
        | "add_timestamps" >> beam.Map(add_timestamps)
```

While launching the pipline I do set the flag:  `--setup_file=./setup.py`.

However not a single element is read into the pipeline (as you can see Data watermark still stuck and Elements added (Approximate) does not report anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause... I was setting the flag `--no_use_public_ips` and had `install_requires=["datetime"]` in `setup.py`..

of-course, without External IP the worker was unable to communicate with python package manager server to install `datetime`. problem solve by not setting the flag `--no_use_public_ips` (I'll look at solution later how to disable external IPs for workers and still be able to run successfully). Would have been good it at least some Error message was displayed in Job/Worker logs! Spent like 2-3 days troubleshooting :=)

Answer (score 1):

I have tested Multiple File dependencies option in Dataflow and for me it works fine. I reproduced example from [Medium](https://medium.com/@rajeshhegde/data-pipeline-using-apache-beam-python-sdk-on-dataflow-6bb8550bf366).

Your directory structure is correct. Have you added any imports in `transforms.py` file?

I would recommend you to make some changes in `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    ‘datetime’
]

PACKAGE_NAME = 'my_transforms'
PACKAGE_VERSION = '0.0.1'

setuptools.setup(
   name=PACKAGE_NAME,
   version=PACKAGE_VERSION,
   description='My transforms package',
   install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
   packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

When running your pipeline, keep an eye on setting the following fields in [PipelineOptions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-execution-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service): `job_name`, `project`, `runner`, `staging_location`, `temp_location`. You must specify at least one of `temp_location` or `staging_location` to run your pipeline on the Google cloud.  If you use the Apache Beam SDK for Python 2.15.0 or later, you must also specify region. Remember about specifying full path to `setup.py`.

It will look similar to that command:

```
python3 pipeline.py \
--job_name <JOB_NAME>
--project <PROJECT_NAME> \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--region <REGION> \
--temp_location gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/temp \
--setup_file /<FULL_PATH>/setup.py
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. All of that was set .. Tried to give */<FULL_PATH>/setup.py* for `--setup_file` but that din't help either.

Comment: I found the root cause - answered above. Would have been good it at least some Error message was displayed in Job/Worker logs! Spent like 2-3 days troubleshooting :=)